How can I handle Elastic.CommonSchema.NLog with Elastic.NLog.Targets
I have nlog.config file which looks like this :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" autoReload="true"    internalLogLevel="Debug" internalLogFile="c:\work\nlog-internal.txt">
<!-- Load the necessary NLog extensions -->
<extensions>
    <add assembly="Elastic.CommonSchema.NLog"/>
    <add assembly="Elastic.NLog.Targets" />
</extensions>
<targets>
  <target name="elastic" xsi:type="ElasticSearch"
       nodeUris="https://uat-example.com:9200"
       username="elastic"
       password= "123">
       <indexFormat>testing</indexFormat>
       <layout xsi:type="EcsLayout">
          <metadata name="url" layout="${url}" />
        </layout>
  </target>
</targets>
<rules>
  <logger name="ElasticsearchLoging.Controllers.HomeController" minLevel="Error" maxLevel="Error" writeTo="elastic" />
</rules>
</nlog>

I want to control the layout and save the "message" field in the Elasticsearch but it is adding additional details as well.
Does anyone knows how can I handle this thing?
Thank you
Update:
Now Log are saved perfectly I just need the control on additional details with logs.

Maybe you can update your question with the an example of current unexpected output, and also an example of the output you want? Notice Elastic.NLog.Targets enforces Json-format that follows Elastic Common Schema
